# Xbox One Controller not detected (loading gamepad.h from DirectXTK without library)

Tags: c++, windows, xbox, gamepad, directxtk

I am using the DirectXTK library for the gamepad class. I compiled the library with only this class inside it and it works.

If I would only add the source files to my project, without the library, the size would be ~50KB instead of ~500KB.

**However, the Xbox One Controller is not detected using the source    files without the library.**

Any ideas on how to resolve this so my executable would be smaller in size?

Comment: is that a disk space issue that is causing you trouble due to bulky executable? or you want to separate the library with the executable and still need that working (use DLL)?

Comment: It is not really an issue, but I prefer to keep the size low and I like to learn more about how to do this. I think that it should be possible and it shouldn't be that difficult either. But I only need to figure out what I need to change to make it work. The entire application is only a few MB, so 500KB is a big part of it :)

Comment: I presume there must be something different between using just the files and using them inside a library which causes it to behave differently

Comment: yes there might be interdependencies. that is a possibility it isn't working correctly. how are you creating the binary file? you might use `-Os` flag if you are using `g++` to compile your code

Comment: library code inside your project. this way the final binary will be optimized.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio targetting a Windows application

Comment: Look at the implementation of ``GamePad``. It's just using either ``XINPUT`` or ``Windows.Gaming.Input`` (Windows 10 platforms). See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/25/xinput-and-windows-8/).